# Не добавляются файлы в каталог web/assets в Yii2 advanced при клонировании проекта

Tags: yii2

При клонировании на другой компьютер проекта на Yii2-advanced слетает вся вёрстка. Файлы в папке frontend/web/assets не появляются, папки появляются, файлы  css  и js нет.
Вводил команду в консоль chmod -R 777 /var/www/adv3/frontend/web ,
не помогло.
Удаляю все папки из каталога  frontend/web/assets, после нескольких обновлений страницы, они вновь появляются, а файлы нет, и в ошибках в логах пишет permission denied.
Что я не так делаю с созданием прав на запись?

Comment: когда я проверяю пользователя и права доступа в каталоге /var/www/adv3/frontend/web, то есть 
$ ls -al

то вижу 

drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant   64 Dec 27 13:17 3036d7ca
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant   64 Dec 27 13:17 35407575
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant   64 Dec 27 13:17 8da20998
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant   64 Dec 27 13:17 de9c3a9a

Comment: Виртуальная машина Ubuntu/trusty 14.04, запущена с помощью vagrant

Comment: Я подозреваю, что это из-за виртальной машины, vagrant, nginx...